# Produckt url send not to top of product page

Tags: woocommerce

please help:
produckt url send not to top of product page.
Only to aditional information (“Dodatkowe informacje” on my page).
See my shop:
category link, than press any product:

direct product link:

How to fix it?
I want to see always the top of product page.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You got some JavaScript that runs after the page load and sends the visitor to the bottom of the page. When you disable JavaScript you will see that the page loads fine.

I couldn't locate that JavaScript in the few minutes I looked into the page. You could try to locate that JavaScript by disabling functions (mainly JavaScripts) of your theme one by one and see if it starts working.

You could also switch to another theme for testing reasons and see if the issue persists. If yes then the problem is not in the theme but within one of your plugins you use.

Comment: Probably I can't disable any JS because than my page don't works like I want. 
It is possible to add CSS code to links with something like position -200px?

Comment: You need to identify the JavaScript that is causing the issue. Then you can decide how to proceed. Maybe you can turn it off. Our maybe you can reconfigure it.